# Spree commerce - taxonomy meny not appearing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

According to documentation [https://guides.spreecommerce.com/user/configuring_taxonomies.html] I am supposed to see a taxonomies menu under the admin lateral menu, however I am not seeing anything.

[image]

Should I do something to enable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is in the "Products" section:

[image]